# dyld: Library not loaded(xcode)

Tags: objective-c, frameworks, xcode4.5, dyld

I was running the code in xcode and Build was succeeded. But i got an error,

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices
  Referenced from: /Users/developer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NKDBarcode-fdnqnjfiwlxcewbfyoyarhsmvvll/Build/Products/Debug/NKDBarcode.app/Contents/MacOS/NKDBarcode
  Reason: Incompatible library version: NKDBarcode requires version 64.0.0 or later, but ApplicationServices provides version 1.0.0
```

I don't know what exactly the error is as im new to this.

Can anyone help me to sort the issue please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Library is incompatible with your AppKit Version

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to have added the framework (ApplicationServices.framework) in the **Link Binary With Libraries** Phase of your target! It should work then.